# Add "Elephant's Foot" in Cura

Tags: slicing, support-structures, warping

Ok, I know this is quite weird since basically, we want to avoid elephant's foot.
But my case is: I want to print some thin/tall stuff which I don't want to lay them down and sometimes it gives me some warped outcomes.

I try some different things and find it if I manually add a thin but big first few layers. It will generate a pretty good result consistently. (And the "Manually Added Elephant Foot" is also easy to be removed)

I'm wondering if I can let the slicer help me add the "elephant foot" as a kind of "support"

Can someone help me to do that or tell me actually I cannot do that?

Comment: What slicer are you using? What printer?

Comment: @TheTridentGuysupportsUkraine I'm using cura + Flsun V400

Answer (score 1):

**Use a brim:**

(I'll assume you're using Cura since you didn't provide FCI.)

Navigate to **Print Settings** > **Build Plate Adhesion** and select **Brim** on the **Build Plate Adhesion Type** dropdown.

You could also use a raft though it seems unwise in this case. For more on brims and rafts, see All3DP.com's article "[Raft vs Brim vs Skirt: The Differences (incl. Cura settings)](https://all3dp.com/2/3d-printing-raft-brim-and-skirt-all-you-need-to-know/)".

Comment: Long thin objects with a raft would not be wise.

Comment: Thx for informations, I will try that